# Transact SQL How to to do?

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2008, sdf

I need to generate a SQL update command in a *.sdf file.

The *.sdf file is deployed using Visual studio. I am looking to generate a script which fills in a table the maximum number of records which is about 2MBytes.

any ideas for how I can do this i.e. connect remotely to the database and script filling in the database with a dummy record? Examples and deployment would be fab :-)

Answer (score 1):

I presume you have a database project in Visual Studio.

In a database project, the post-deployment script is executed in Command mode. You can use the following syntax to execute any commands that you want executed.

```
:r "filepath\filename.ext"
```

Comment: please can you provide more details as the sdf file exists in the project solution in visual studio. I would like take the sdf file and update the database file to fill into the max size. Basically looking for a simple loop to go through a table and add in a record for max size number of entries.

Thnxes :-)

Comment: do you have a database project?

Comment: I do nto have  a database project. I have a SDF file added as an item in Visual Studio and this has been defined with a resource file for the column names. There is a query tool in Visual Studio but I am not able to loop with it. Please can you give me in simple terms how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

`Visual Studio Team Systems for Database Developers` will do this for you.

Comment: Please can you provide how and where I can get this and whether there is a simple tutorial to know how to get the simple setup?